# How to resolve No such property:Gradle Version for classes :jetGradleplugin?

Tags: android, gradle

I get the project from github. When I want to build that project, I get this Error:

```
 No such property:Gradle Version for classes :jetGradleplugin
```

My build api version is 28 and my gradle version is 5.1.1 .
How can I resolve this?

Comment: hi zehra welcome to SO. can u please show us your project level and app level graddle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats because you use another version of gradle! try to change it from gradle-wrapper.properties, to whatever you use in your other projects.
If it doesn't work for you, then you have to update your android studio.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to build a project you downloaded/cloned for GitHub, correct? Then, you should probably check your gradle version, because if [this](https://github.com/excelsior-oss/excelsior-jet-gradle-plugin/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) is the mentioned project, then you need version 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Android Studio 3.0. In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, I downgraded gradle `distributionUrl` from `gradle-5.4.1-all.zip` to `gradle-4.1-all.zip`, and in the preject `build.gradle`, I changed the gradle version in `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'` from `3.5.1` to `3.0.0`. I synced the project then and the problem was solved.